# 404 redirect header showing 302

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, http-headers, http-status-code-302

In my application i wrote below code for 404.

```
   Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim exc As Exception
            Dim readdInfo As New NameValueCollection

            exc = Server.GetLastError()
            Dim httpCode As Integer = CType(exc, HttpException).GetHttpCode()
            If httpCode = 404 Then
                If TypeOf Context.CurrentHandler Is System.Web.UI.Page Then
                    Context.Server.Transfer("404.aspx")
                    Context.Response.Flush()
                    Context.Response.End()
                Else
                    Context.RewritePath("404.aspx")
                    Context.Response.Clear()
                    Context.Response.ClearContent()
                    Context.Response.ClearHeaders()
                    **Context.CurrentHandler.ProcessRequest(Context)**
                    Context.Response.Flush()
                    Context.Response.End()
                End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

But when i try to run above program i am getting  **Context.CurrentHandler** is null exception.
If i keep Response.Redirect in place of Server.Transfer I am getting 301 header.
I've used http://404checker.com/full-header-checker for header checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but a Response.Redirect is a 302:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
```

Your Context.CurrentHandler check is before the Server.Transfer so that has nothing to do with your null exception.

Comment: When i check in http://404checker.com/full-header-checker with not exist page ,the header is showing HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved instead of  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found